# O que é um servidor RTMP e como se conectar a ele com SharedObject do Flash?

Tags: lado-do-servidor, actionscript-3, código-aberto, cliente-servidor

Estou precisando criar um arquivo `SharedObject` do Flash em um servidor na internet para a comunicação entre diversos `.SWFs`. É preciso que esta comunicação seja rápida e se possível em real-time. Após algumas pesquisas no site de [Referência da Adobe](http://help.adobe.com/pt_BR/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/net/SharedObject.html#getRemote%28%29), encontrei o seguinte código:

```js
var nc:NetConnection = new NetConnection();
nc.connect("rtmp://somedomain.com/applicationName");
var myRemoteSO:SharedObject = SharedObject.getRemote("mo", nc.uri, false);
myRemoteSO.connect(nc);
```

Pelo que eu entendi, é preciso possuir um servidor `RTMP`, que é um tipo de Servidor de Media usado pelo Flash para tratar de medias live-streaming e também de dados com o `SharedObject`.

Neste [link](http://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Real_Time_Messaging_Protocol) do Wikipedia eu encontrei um servidor de media Open-Source chamado [Red5](http://www.red5.org/), mas estou com dificuldades de aprender a usá-lo.

Alguém já trabalhou com este tipo de servidor? Existe algum que seja gratuito? Posso integrá-lo no Wamp Server, por exemplo? Como funciona a conexão com este servidor?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Servidor RTMP nada mais é do que um servidor de mídia para distribuição de conteúdo ao vivo e sob-demanda. Estes servidores são independentes e tem seus próprios módulos.

Existem vários softwares no mercado, porém os mais usados são:

Wowza Media Server: http://www.wowza.com/ (pago)
Adobe Media Server: http://www.adobe.com/br/products/adobe-media-server-family.html (pago)
E o Red5 que é free.

Se você deseja ter um servidor RTMP para oferecer este serviço a terceiros, você precisa ter um bom servidor, juntando bom processamento de dados e rede. Dependendo da sua necessidade, você pode utilizar um servidor fora do país para que possa reduzir custos e ter uma ótima infraestrutura.

Existem muitas ofertas para este tipo de serviço no mercado, onde toda a infraestrutura fica a cargo da empresa de hospedagem e você trataria apenas de fazer a transmissão.

Procure no Google por Streaming de Vídeo e analise as ofertas prestando atenção no valor e o número de usuários simultâneos.

Com relação ao seu código, ficaria assim:

```
var nc:NetConnection = new NetConnection();
// Na linha abaixo é feita a requisição para o servidor
nc.connect("rtmp://ip-ou-host-do-servidor:1935/live/live");
var myRemoteSO:SharedObject = SharedObject.getRemote("mo", nc.uri, false);
myRemoteSO.connect(nc);
```

Para que isto funcione, você precisaria estar enviando dados para o servidor, usando programas como o Adobe Flash Live Encoder : http://www.adobe.com/br/products/flash-media-encoder.html

Segue a documentação do Wowza Media Server para que possa esclarecer melhor suas dúvidas:

http://www.wowza.com/forums/content.php?217-Quick-Start-Guide

Ainda existem os serviços públicos sem custo algum, porém com qualidade de serviço reduzida. Segue abaixo alguns deles:

http://www.zstream.eu/
http://livestreamcast.org/
http://www.justin.tv/
http://new.livestream.com/
http://www.ustream.tv/
http://www.livecast.com/
http://www.google.com/+/learnmore/hangouts/onair.html